# hot not to commit twice same functionality in tortoisesvn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Simple question about version control.

I'm changing the files in the project, doing commit. For example, I commited, and then made some little ​​changes. 
If i commit again, there will be 2 commit entries in SVN history on the same functionality. 
What I have to do in such case? Merge or so?

Using SVN and TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 2):

If the changes are distinct (e.g. fixed one bug and then another one after some time) it's natural to have several changes - they represent history of evolution of the code.

If several changes are very related to each other, it may make sense to branch, do there all changes and then merge to the trunk producing single commit.

Answer (score 0):

> What I have to do in such case?

Nothing. **History in Subversion is immutable** - from client-side you can not change (alter, collapse, move) it